# What is the cheapest way in .net to determine enumeration-vs-number?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, string-parsing

I am trying to determine whether a given string is an enumeration value or not.  It is rather common that the string should be a decimal value.   My question is whether it takes longer to do an `Enum.TryParse()` on the string or to do a regex check that it is a decimal value or do a `Int32.TryParse()`.   If the string is not a numeric (unsigned) decimal value, it is highly likely, but not 100% guaranteed, that the string is an enum value.

This check is made many many times.  I want to get the lowest average cost.

Comment: Regex are expensive in CPU time

Comment: Write some benchmarks and see :-) My initial guess is that checking the first character to see if it's a character will be the fastest method of predicting if the value is likely of an enum.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - `Enum.TryParse` will succeed with numeric values as well. It would really help if you'd give a concrete example, including sample input and expected output.

Comment: You're going to be better off running benchmarks yourself. No one here knows your dataset, loop nuances, or other unique circumstances.

Comment: When you compile regex however the performance hit is mostly in the startup.

Comment: What is "many many times?" If you're doing a million of these a second, you might worry about the time taken. Otherwise a simple `if (!int.TryParse(...)) { Enum.TryParse(...) }` is easy to code and will perform well.

Comment: What is the question?  Decimal is not Int32.

Comment: Strings are for humans, ints and enums are for computers.  You'll have to convert a string after you obtained it with I/O or a user interface.  At which point perf is a non-issue, obtaining the string is already much more expensive than converting it.  Optimizing it won't make the operation noticeably faster.

Answer (score 1):

You should profile your code to determine if this is actually a problem. If not, just do whatever gives you the most clear, concise (working) code. If it is a problem, this is probably a good way to pick which approach to use:

```
bool probablyANumber = char.IsDigit(myStr[0]);
```

This should work well because enums can't start with digits, while numbers usually do (with exceptions like `"-1"` and `" 1 "`). Whether this is an improvement or just makes things worse depends on your data set.

It's worth noting that `enum`s [can be parsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from numbers, so the behavior of `Enum.TryParse` may not be what you were expecting.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Zero,
    One,
    Two,
    Ten = 10
}

MyEnum e;
Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>("10", out e);
// success; e == MyEnum.Ten

MyEnum e;
Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>("11", out e);
// success; e == (MyEnum)11
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest?  Put the string values in a HashSet.  HashSet.Contains()